# Can you access the controller name from within a webapi ExceptionHandler or ExceptionLogger

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using a webapi ExceptionHandler and ExceptionLogger to ensure consistent logging and handling of exceptions at the controller level in my web api projects.

I want to log the controller name in which the exception occurred but I find that the ActionContext and ControllerContext are always null even when the exception is originating in a controller during a request.

The documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) states (underneath the ExceptionContext class) that

> When the framework calls an exception logger or an exception handler, it will always provide an Exception and a Request. Except for unit testing, it will also always provide a RequestContext. It will rarely provide a ControllerContext and ActionContext (only when calling from the catch block for exception filters).

Is there an alternate way of being able to log the Controller Class Name from within the Handler / Logger?

Answer (score 0):

Use the format below:

```
new ExceptionResult(ex, controller)
```

where **ex** is the exception and **controller** is the controller name

Comment: but I don't know the controller name, that's the point of the question